# MVC 2 website - Cant get a list of files in the images folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-io

I have created a wedsite using MVC 2 and C#. one of the pages is a gallery of product images. i have stored the path to the pictures in the Db eg ../../Content/ProductImages/
in the controler i want to do a foreach and get a list of the files to dispaly. i tried the code below :

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeModel.ArtUrl); // ../../Content/ProductImages/

foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
   files.Add(f);
}
```

BUT i get an error, Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Content\ProductImages\'.

Why is it getting the wrong path ?? this path does not exist

Would be most grateful if anyone could tell me how to get a list of the files contained in 
../../Content/ProductImages/

Thanks
John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
string path = Server.MapPath(typeModel.ArtUrl);
```

MSDN [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use `Server.MapPath(typeModel.ArtUrl);` to have the real location